# Is it really possible to use Xamarin Forms to share all views and view controllers?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I apologize if this is somewhat too open-ended of a question, but I'm still parsing everything about the Xamarin framework and it's hard to know even what to ask.

Everything I've read claims it's possible to, in theory, write a Xamarin app that has the same views and view controllers for both Android and iOS. The app I am developing has a very comprehensive design that uses almost no native look and feel, so I understand I will need to override the default platform's L&F. Because of this, it seems an ideal candidate to reuse everything for both device platforms, and Xamarin.Forms seems the ideal candidate.

However, I've yet to find a good example that does this. Even all of Microsoft's official examples of Xamarin.Forms (such as https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/BoxView/BasicBoxView)  use ViewControllers/AXML files for iOS/Android. Huh? Isn't the point of Forms so I *don't* have to do that? Why are they mixing Forms and the native Xamarin in an example targeted towards Forms? Is this a sign it's not really possible?

Xamarin seems very flexible, which is great, but I'm also finding it confusing determining what will work together and what will not, plus how to determine the best solution.

Thanks.

Comment: That example you linked to is a XAML-based Forms' example, it is not defining native iOS storyboards or Android layouts. Yes, the Xamarin.Forms controls are rendered using native controls and thus each platform looks different. Is that your actual question?

Comment: the BoxView sample contains NO platform specific implementation or Views, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Yes, you can get 100% code sharing, but it really depends on the nature of your app and its requirements.  If you want perfect UI fidelity between all platforms then this will require more work.

Comment: Visual is a new approach to providing more fidelity between UI on different platforms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual

Comment: @Jason I guess I have no idea what I'm talking about. I thought Forms was intended to write UI code for both platforms. So why does the BoxView sample, which was linked to under "Xamarin.Forms examples", not contain any?

Comment: @SushiHangover It does contain native Android layouts, though.  Look under /BasicBoxView/BasicBoxView/BasicBoxView.Android/Resources/layout

Comment: it does - there is a MainPage.xaml file which is the UI for all platforms.  It's only a single page example

Comment: @MarkHerscher Those two layouts are default inflater layouts and *you* do not create them (they are from the template creation).

Comment: the stuff in Android/resources is (I think) mostly boilerplate.  Any Forms project is going to contain one project per-supported-platform that contains boottrapping code the that platform as well as some boilerplate stuff which you may or may not ever need to touch

Comment: Ah, I see. That's very confusing (maybe only to me) for them to leave non-relevant files in an example.